# Apple Signin returns 'invalid_grant' on web but app doesn't

Tags: ios, react-native, oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in

I'm applying Apple Signin on both app and web. But Apple server always returns error `invalid_grant` if I signin in web and verifying it.

The following is simple environment for my service.

The app is made by ReactNative and the server is nodejs.

The Certificate values are, for example, following.

```
TeamID : 9BF12A
AppID : com.foo
ServiceID : com.foo.web (its bound primary key(?) is AppID com.foo)
KeyID : 12ABC4 (its bound primary key(?) is AppID com.foo)
...
```

And when signin in the app, it sends `authorizationCode` and `identityToken` to the server url `/auth/apple`.

When signin in the web, it open the Apple signin page. And when complete the signin process, the Apple returns the `code` and `id_token` to the server url `/auth/apple` (referencing [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple)).

So, in my server route `/auth/apple`, I receive `code(authorizationCode)` and `id_token(identityToken)` from the app and web.

And to verify the `id_token`, I make `client_secret` and verify the `code` using following functions

```
// isrn : if the values(code and id_token) are come from the app(react native)
const get_client_secret = isrn => {
  // sign with RSA SHA256
  const privateKey = get_private_key(); // pseudo
  const token = jwt.sign({}, privateKey, {
    algorithm: 'ES256',
    expiresIn: '10h',
    audience: 'https://appleid.apple.com',
    issuer: 9BF12A, // TeamID
    subject: isrn ? com.foo : com.foo.web, // if the code from react native app, use AppID, else use ServiceID
    keyid: 12ABC4,
  });

  return token;
};


const verify = (code, isrn) => {
  let b;
  let e;

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    axios.post(
      'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token',
      querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code,
        client_secret: get_client_secret(isrn),
        client_id: isrn ? com.foo : com.foo.web,
        redirect_uri: 'https://testurl.com/auth/apple',
      }),
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
      })
    .then(r => {
      b = r.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      e = err.response ? err.response.data : { err };
    })
    .finally(() => {
      resolve({ b, e });
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    resolve({ b, e: err });
  });
};
```

And I just use it in route `/auth/apple` like

```
app.post('/auth/apple', (req, res, _) => {
  const { body: { isrn, code, id_token } } = req;

  verify(code, isrn).then(({ b, e }) => {

    // if code came from the app, b has result values like access_token and e is undefined
    // but if code came from the web, b is undefined and e has value 'invalid_grant'
    log('******* verify : ', b, e);

    // some process
  });
});
```

When the `code` and `id_token` come from web, the error is returned with `invalid_grant` but in case of app, the return value is fine.

How can I verify the `code` which come from the web like the app does?

Or, I couldn't ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a code which has not been expired.

> The authorization code received in an authorization response sent to
>   your app. The code is single-use only and valid for five minutes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

Comment: as I write, I used the `code` right after I received. Is it possible the `code` is expired after I received ?